# Elements in fractional Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the fractional Sobolev space consists of those elements $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
||f||^{2}_{L^2}(\mathbb{R^n})+\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dx dy<\infty.
$$
The space $L^2(t_1,t_2;H^s(\mathbb{R}^n))$ consists of those $v:\mathbb{R^n}\times(t_1.t_2)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}|v|^2 dx dt+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\frac{|v(x,t)-v(y,t)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dx dy dt<\infty.
$$
Let $u\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a bounded function. Let $\psi:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth and $\eta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth with compact support. Then if $p>1$, is the function $\phi(x,t)=u^p\psi(x)\eta(t)\in L^2(t_1,t_2;H^s(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Can anybody give some hint. Thanks.

Comment: The question essentially reduces to: Does the product $fg\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and g is in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?